# "npx expo run:android" command does not run in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

`npx expo run:android` not working. There is no method I haven't tried. What should I do? Thanks.

```
PS C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app> npx expo run:android
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\expo-modules-autolinking\scripts\android\autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 356

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-modules-core'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.PropertiesProvider.JvmTargetValidationMode.WARN¦NG
      > KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'debugAndroidTest' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU¦LD FAILED in 13s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
Error: C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:303:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:36:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: Run ```npx expo start``` then focus the terminal and press “a“for android or “i” for ios

Comment: @MichaelBahl I already know this. I want to build locally.

Comment: Try ```npx eas build -p android --local ```

Comment: @MichaelBahl I know other commands. I just need the "npx expo run:android" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded kotlin version to 1.9.0 with `expo-build-properties` and it worked.

Expo Docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {

    ...

    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "kotlinVersion": "1.9.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, well done.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect your conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with Kotlin configuration in your Gradle scripts, particularly with the enum constant `JvmTargetValidationMode` and the missing `KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation`.

To be sure, check your Kotlin plugin is up to date in your Gradle configuration, and that you are using a [compatible version of Gradle and the Android Gradle Plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#apply-the-plugin) with your project (`./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=<latest_version>`, see [Gradle releases](https://gradle.org/releases/)).
Clean your project and invalidate caches if using Android Studio (`./gradlew clean`).
Try and rebuild the project.

If the issue persists, consider checking the specific line mentioned in the error (line: 356 of `autolinking_implementation.gradle`) to see if there is a syntax error or an issue with the script.
See also "[Expo build Troubleshoot build errors and crashes](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting/)"

---

What is mentioned above is for troubleshooting the `npx expo run:android` command.

Since you are building locally:

- Make sure the Kotlin version in your project is compatible with the Expo SDK version you are using. The error suggests a possible mismatch in Kotlin's expected properties and the ones defined in your project.
- Since the error points to a line in the `autolinking_implementation.gradle` script, inspect that line for any issues related to Kotlin configuration. It may be referencing a Kotlin enum or configuration that does not match the installed Kotlin version.
- Execute the build command with the `--stacktrace` option to get a detailed trace of the error, which can provide some clues.

```bash
npx expo run:android --stacktrace
```

Remember to synchronize the changes with your project by running the following after making updates:

```bash
npx expo start --clear
```

Note that the `npx eas build -p android --local` command is for EAS Build, which is different from the Expo CLI's `run:android` command. The `run:android` command is designed to run your project on a local Android emulator or device, and it should work with the correct configuration and compatible versions of the tools involved.

---

The [OP Blogger Klik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19309011/blogger-klik)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77438341/6309) confirms that upgrading kotlin version to 1.9.0 with `expo-build-properties` was enough.

Using `expo-build-properties` to configure native build properties such as the Kotlin version is an excellent approach to managing compatibility within an Expo project.

For future reference or for others facing similar issues, you can apply those changes by installing `expo-build-properties` if it is not already added to your project:

```bash
expo install expo-build-properties
```

Then configure the Kotlin version in your `app.json` or `app.config.js`:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "kotlinVersion": "1.9.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

See "[Expo BuildProperties](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/)".

After making changes to the configuration, rebuild your project:

```bash
npx expo run:android
```

That method allows for fine-grained control over the native build process, making it easier to align with the necessary versions of Kotlin and other build tools that your Expo project depends on.

Comment: “Make sure the version of Kotlin in your project is compatible with the version of Expo SDK you are using.” How can I learn and change these?

Comment: @BloggerKlik Open your project's `package.json` file and look for the expo package version. And in your project, check the Kotlin version specified in the `build.gradle` (`project-level` or `app-level`) file, typically found as `ext.kotlin_version` or directly within dependencies as `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"`.

Comment: Kotlin version in build.gradle is 1.8.10. Expo is 49.0.15. I already know these and I have never changed them. Why are these incompatible? I meant how can I find out if it is compatible or incompatible?

Comment: @BloggerKlik that is what the 'compatible version " part of my answer is addressing: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#apply-the-plugin